# PTAM CameraCalibrator error

Tags: ros, cameras, calibration

I am trying to run the `cameracalibrator.launch` using PTAM according to this [Camera Calibration tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/Tutorials/camera_calibration). However, when I do so, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ptam/cameracalibrator]: can't locate node [cameracalibrator] in package [ptam]
```

I source my `devel/setup.bash` before I run the code as well and it still does not work. Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="cameracalibrator" pkg="ptam" type="cameracalibrator" clear_params="true" output="screen">
        <remap from="image_raw" to usb_cam/image_raw" />
        <remap from="pose" to="pose"/>
        <rosparam file="$(find ptam)/PtamFixParams.yaml"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

Here is what I get for `rostopic list`:

```
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/svo/dense_input
/svo/image
/svo/image/compressed
/svo/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions
...
/tf
/usb_cam/camera_info
/usb_cam/image_raw
/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed
...
/usb_cam/image_raw/theora
/usb_cam/image_raw/parameter_descriptions
/usb_cam/image_raw/parameter_updates
```

The path where the `cameracalibration.launch` file is `catkin_ws/src/ethzasl_ptam/ptam/launch`.

I am not sure why this error keeps coming up because when I run `roslaunch ptam cameracalibrator.launch`, it says:

```
NODES
  /
    cameracalibrator (ptam/cameracalibrator)
```

So I'm thinking that PTAM does include `cameracalibrator`. If someone could please point out my error, that would be really helpful. I've been using this post as a guide, but it's not been helping me much: [Ros Dynamic Config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759356/ros-dynamic-config-file).

As it says in the above link, I tried `find . -executable` and I could not find `cameracalibrator`. I could only find the below. How do I proceed?

```
./include
./include/ptam
./cfg
...
./launch
./src
./src/ptam
./src/ptam/cfg
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [camera_calibration package](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration). It's supported in all distributions. The package you're using looks pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the node by typing "rosrun ptam" and then hitting the tab key. If it doesn't show up there, most likely there's something wrong with your package path. I am surprised it works with the other launch file. Did you check the difference between the two launch files? From where (which directories) are you launching them?